# Convert from the CMSampleBuffer to a UIImage object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, avfoundation

I tried an example for capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation that is given in documentation  i.e.,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

But in delegate method to get the UIImage object from the `CMSampleBufferRef` the method that has given is not building.

Means I have imported AVFoundation framework also but it is giving 14 errors like `_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress`, referenced from: .

If any one know how to solve please help me.

Thanks in advance .Please if any one know tell to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't AVFoundation link with my XCode 3.2.3 iPhone 4.0.1 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393239/why-wont-avfoundation-link-with-my-xcode-3-2-3-iphone-4-0-1-project)

Comment: @Kenny TM : Thank u for ur response. Yes after importing corevideo its working. And I am getting the UIImage object in delegate method but if i tried to display the UIImage using UIImageView means          UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
 img.frame = CGRectMake(10,120, 100, 100);
 [self.view addSubview:img]; like this the image is not displaying ......

Answer (score 2):

This is the code to capture and get the image from captured data:

```
-(IBAction)startCapture
{
    //session object
    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
    previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 200); ////self.view.frame; //
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //input object
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *inputDevice = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc]initWithDevice:device error:&error];
    [captureSession addInput:inputDevice];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [captureSession addOutput:stillImageOutput];
    [captureSession startRunning];
}

-(IBAction) captureNow
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);

         NSLog(@"exif Attachments:%@",exifAttachments);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
             self.vImage.image = image;
             // Do something with the attachments.

         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");   
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal - are you trying to record video to a video file. Or just capture specific frames? I have a working example of capturing a video file with audio using AVCaptureSession, if it would help I can post some code snippets - but seeing as there are a few bits and bobs involved I would like to know specifically what you are trying to do.

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Here my theme is to capture the video and need to display it as a video file or image . I got how to get image from capturing video frames but if i try to display using UIImageView or save it into photo album it is not working.

Comment: Did u get what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To save to the library once the assetWriter has finished recording the movie/capturing the image.

Put this at the top above the implementation file *this is example of saving a video file but you could change that to save your image:

```
ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock _videoCompblock = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
if(assetURL){
    NSLog(@"Saved to camera roll with Video AssetUrl : %@", [assetURL absoluteString]);
    NSError *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:[assetURL absoluteString] error:&error];

    if (attributes){
        long fileSize = [[attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] longValue];// unsigned long long
        NSLog(@"%d", fileSize);
    }

}else if(error){
    NSLog(@"The Error occured : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

};

Then you need a function that uses the above block - so when you capture session finishes recording have something like this:

```
-(void) stopRecording{
writing = NO;
isRecording = NO;
[audioInput markAsFinished];//if you have an audio writer stop it too
[videoInput markAsFinished];
[assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:[frTimer currentTimeStamp]];
[assetWriter finishWriting];

finished = YES;

[videoUtilities saveToCamera:[assetWriter outputURL]];
NSLog(@"%@", [[assetWriter outputURL] absoluteString]);
```

}

which triggers the save to camera function which will look kinda like this:

```
+(void) saveToCamera:(NSURL *)urlPath{

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

AVAsset *movFile = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:urlPath options:nil];
NSLog(@"Movie File %@", movFile);

BOOL isSupported = [library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:urlPath];

if(isSupported){
    NSLog(@"IS SUPPORTED - SAVING TO CAMERA ROLL");
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:urlPath completionBlock:_videoCompblock];

}
```

}

If you are trying to display the saved image realtime as you take it - you need to copy the UIImageData to a UIImage object when you take the photo - and assign that as the image for the UIImageView. Or you can just enumerate through the assetLibrary and pull it from there.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Thank u. But I didn't get how to use ur code in my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import CoreMedia.framework and CoreVideo.framework